# Collapse/Compress a matrix, moving non-zero elements to the left

Tags: arrays, matlab, compression, reshape

I am trying to collapse an array such that the follow examples are met

```
v = [ 1 2 3; 0 0 1; 0 1 0]
```

will push up all non-zero elements to the left such that I would be left with

```
v = [1 2 3; 0 1 1;]
```

Another case that I would need to satisfy is for example

```
v2 = [1 2 3; 1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 0]
```

becomes

```
v2 = [1 2 3; 1 1 0; 1 0 0]
```

So basically I  am squeezing the matrix up by pushing all non-zero values to the left in their corresponding column. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "pushing to the left" or do you mean "pushing to the top"? Your examples seem to suggest the latter...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which can reproduce your examples. See the comments for details

```
function A = pushmatrixup(A)
    % Loop over each column of matrix A
    for col = 1:size(A,2)       
        % Rearrange the values in column 'col', with the logic:
        % [Values in column 'col' which don't equal 0;
        %  Values in column 'col' which do equal 0]
        A(:,col) = [A(A(:,col) ~= 0, col); A(A(:,col) == 0, col)];
    end
    % All columns now have their 0s 'sunk' to the bottom of the column.
end
```

Checks:

```
pushmatrixup(v)

ans =
 1     2     3
 0     1     1
 0     0     0


pushmatrixup(v2)

ans =
 1     2     3
 1     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     0
```

---

Edit: If the non-zero values are always *greater* than zero too, you could simply use `sort`...

```
sort(v2, 'descend')
```

---

The second part to this is removing the all-zero rows at the bottom. Extending the `pushmatrixup` function, or doing this after a `sort`...

```
function A = pushmatrixup(A)
    % Loop over each column of matrix A
    for col = 1:size(A,2)       
        % Rearrange the values in column 'col', with the logic:
        % [Values in column 'col' which don't equal 0;
        %  Values in column 'col' which do equal 0]
        A(:,col) = [A(A(:,col) ~= 0, col); A(A(:,col) == 0, col)];
    end
    % All columns now have their 0s 'sunk' to the bottom of the column.

    % Remove the all-zero rows
    % Loop from bottom to top on rows until one has a non-zero value
    for rw = size(A,1):-1:1
        if any(A(rw,:) ~= 0)
            % Break if non-zero element found in row
            break
        end
    end
    % rw is row number of row with all zero elements, as loop was
    % broken when this condition was broken. Cut A off at row rw.
    A = A(1:rw,:);        
end
```